# exception : invalid nulll pointer when loading object saved in file

Tags: c++, exception, null

So ive been trying to save a whole structure data into a file and then read it back from  the file you can see here in my code i am writing data to the struct (entered  by user) which is then being saved into a file using the myFile.write function to save an object

As in the code below when the program runs for first time and i enter data after doing so when i goto menu back again and then press 2 for load data it works and loads data successfully (which i think).after that it goes back to menu and i press 3 and it shows all the flights i created (Obviously because the data is currently in the main memory and is not being ready by file)

```
    //Global Variables
    string savedFlight = "airportsDB\\SavedFlights.txt"; //path
    const unsigned short NUMBER_OF_AIRPORTS = 8;
    int gFlightSize=0;
    ifstream rFlightData;
    ofstream wFlightData;
    //SKipped some part
    struct flight {
    airport depature;
    airport arrival;
    double crsAlt;
    double distance;
    double fuel;
    void flight::createFlight();
    void flight::showFlight();
};

    void flight::createFlight() {
            cout << "Please insert depature airport (ICAO) : ";
            cin>>depature.icao;

        if(searchapt(depature.icao)){
            cout << "Please insert arrival airport (ICAO) : ";
            cin>>arrival.icao;

                if(searchapt(arrival.icao)){
                    cout<<"Enter Cruise Altitude [3000<Altitude<50000]  : ";
                    cin>>crsAlt;

                    if(crsAlt>50000 || crsAlt<3000){
                    cout<<"Unable CruiseAltitude Please put DIGITS* between 50,000ft and 3,000ft ";
                    }
                    else{
                        //CNTINUE HERE
                    }
            }

            else{
            cout<<"Arrival Airport Does Not Exist In DataBase";
            }
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Departure Airport Does Not Exist In DataBase";
        }
}

    void flight::showFlight(){
                        cout<<"\n Departure Airport : "<<depature.icao
                        <<"\n Arrival   Airport : "<<arrival.icao
                        <<"\n Cruise Altitude   : "<<crsAlt
                        <<"\n\n__________________________________________________\n\n";
    }

    //(Skipped some part)
        void writeFlightData(){
        int i=gFlightSize;
        cout<<"How many flights do you want to add : ";
        cin>>gFlightSize;
        saveCounter(gFlightSize);

    flights=new flight[gFlightSize];

    wFlightData.open(savedFlight,ios::app);

    textColor(12);
    cout<<"USE UPPERCASE LETTER !\n";
    textColor(15);

    while(i<gFlightSize){
            flights[i].createFlight();
            wFlightData.write((char *)&flights[i], sizeof(flights[i]));
            i++;
    }
    wFlightData.close();
}

void loadFlightData(){

    rFlightData.open(savedFlight);// , ios::in); // open file for reading

    cout << "  Loading Saved flights from disk";
    for(int i=3;i>0;i--){ //REVERSE LOOP FOR A TWIST
                cout<<" . ";
                Sleep(800);
            }
    cls 

    if(rFlightData.fail()){
        cout << "\nAn error occured while loading Saved Flights from disk .The file is corrupt or does not exist on the specified path\n\a"<<"\n Press any key to go back to the menu";
        saveCounter(0);
        _getch();
        cls
    }
    else{   

        Sleep(1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < gFlightSize; i++) {
            rFlightData.read((char *)&flights[i], sizeof(flights[i])); // read an object from a file
        }
        cout<<"  Data Load Successfull!  ";
        rFlightData.close(); // close the file
    }
}
```

I am saving an addition counter which is read when program starts again  and it knows the size of flights i added

Now the Issue is when i close this program and run it again and press 2 to load the data it does not load the data but it crashes and gives an exception error "Invalid null pointer"

*
 Debug Assertion Failed!
Program C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP110D.dll
file : f\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86_\crt\src\istream
Line : 734

Expression : Invalid null pointer

For information on how ... 
(Press Retry to debug the application)

*

Comment: here is the menu that i made   cout<<"  1) Create new flight\n";
  cout<<"  2) Load created flights -------------- >  (Necessary Prior to *Find created flight* once)   \n";
  cout<<"  3) Show created flights\n";
  cout<<"  4) Exit\n\n";

Comment: And when you debug it, what does it tell you? Perhaps that `flights` is not set when loading data? Where is the `flights = new Flights[]`? But serializing this way usually DOESN'T work.

Comment: How is the `airport` type declared?

Comment: flight *flights;

Comment: Why are you saving binary data in a".txt" file? (The most likely problem is that your `airport` is not [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable), for instance containing `std::string`s.)

Comment: if you mean the ICAOs they are string 
const unsigned short NUMBER_OF_AIRPORTS=8;
struct airport{
 string icao;
 string city;
}airports[NUMBER_OF_AIRPORTS]

Comment: I have tried saving it in a .Dat file and got same error i dont know if there any other format that might fix the proble,

Comment: @HarisMalik The suffix is irrelevant; what matters is how you're saving the data, not the name of the file. Files with a ".txt" suffix are usually expected to contain text, but that's not what you're writing.

Comment: If the data isnt supposed to be saved in txt ,  i cant guess it , what could be the possible solution to it ?I have a similar program that saves data and after re running it , it loads the data from file without an error ?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it out myself , sorry that the question was a bit unclear .
it was a logical  error as i was using a dynamic array of structure 
while taking data from user similarly when i was trying to load data i did not assign the pointer a new dynamic location where the array of struct could be made and then load data into the struct in program so all i had to do was write

```
flights=new flight[gFlightSize];
```

in my loaddata function like this , so before loading a dynamic location could be assigned in the main memory to the struct where the data could then be loaded into

```
void loadFlightData(){
flights=new flight[gFlightSize];
rFlightData.open(savedFlight);// , ios::in); // open file for reading

cout << "  Loading Saved flights from disk";
for(int i=3;i>0;i--){ //REVERSE LOOP FOR A TWIST
            cout<<" . ";
            Sleep(800);
        }
cls 

if(rFlightData.fail()){
    cout << "\nAn error occured while loading Saved Flights from disk .The file is corrupt or does not exist on the specified path\n\a"<<"\n Press any key to go back to the menu";
    saveCounter(0);
    _getch();
    cls
}
else{   

    Sleep(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < gFlightSize; i++) {
        rFlightData.read((char *)&flights[i], sizeof(flights[i])); // read an object from a file
    }
    cout<<"  Data Load Successfull!  ";
    rFlightData.close(); // close the file
}
}
```